# Wrapping message constants in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, linkage

I have a series of constant strings that correspond to message IDs; I'm trying to create a centralized place for these constants as they are used in various classes in my application. I was originally going to create a namespace containing them:

```
// MessageIDs.hh
namespace MessageIDs {
  const std::string kMessage1("Message1");
  ...
}
```

Then I started to read about internal/external linkage definitions and now I have a couple of questions.

1) Is the only disadvantage of not making the constants extern the fact that I wouldn't be able to use them as template arguments since they would have internal linkage?

2) Is there any other downside to my approach I am unaware of?

Comment: I would use a global `enum` for this instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I see one definite advantage of this approach: you always see the value of the defined constant in the right place. I.e. should the constants be defined extern, you would have to place the definitions in one cpp-file along with the initializers, and leave the header with extern const without the value, which would mislead the supporters a bit.

The downside you mentioned (unability to use them as a template parameter), is really a minor one, do you often need a std::string template parameter? I haven't seen those thankfully.

2) Maybe another minor one is that you have duplicate std::string objects actually in every translation unit including the header file, one can think of it as a downside.

In this particular case of string constants it looks like const char* is the all-cases-best solution.

Comment: The duplication can be removed (under msvc) with `__declspec(selectany)`, which makes the linker pick only one object and strip the rest (msvc also allows `extern const` for header only externally visible objects, see `xnamath.h` for an example).

Comment: The reason I went with string objects is because I thought with char* I would incur overhead everytime I tried using one of these constants since I would have to create a string object each time. (Ex as a function argument)